# Custom toolbar implementation with images

Tags: android, android-layout, toolbar, android-toolbar

How do I implememt such a toolbar? Notice that the area above the toolbar where the icons for wifi and other stuff also has the image. That is what I am interested in. How do I implement this?

[image: Custom toolbar image]

Comment: Use this https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager. And make activity full screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this toolbar with a CoordinatorLayout.

More informations here  [CodePath CoordinatorLayout](http://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout)